# Query on neo4j parent class doesnot return anything

Tags: django, neo4j, neo4django

I have defined the parent class of `Person`, and a subclass of `Father` as following:

```
class Person(models.NodeModel):

    first_name = models.StringProperty()
    middle_name = models.StringProperty()
    last_name = models.StringProperty()

class Father (Person)

    Profession = models.StringProperty()
```

After creating a number of `Father`s, I can easily get all of them by `Father.objects.all()`. However, by running the code `Person.objects.all()` nothing is found (i.e. `[]`)!

As far as I know the last query should return objects as well! Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using neo4django?

If so, I believe this is fixed in master [on GitHub](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django). You can install from GitHub using pip- `pip install -e git+https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/#egg=neo4django`. If it still isn't working, consider raising an issue and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Yes the new version is perfect. It works pretty fine. Thanks.